# running struts project with weblogic server in eclipse

Tags: java, maven, struts2, java-8, weblogic11g

I am new to struts and trying to setup a basic struts application with weblogic server in eclipse.

while running the project with the basic jsp, web xml,struts xml and action i am getting the below error

```
####<Feb 20, 2017 12:45:31 AM IST> <Error> <HTTP> <Gaurav-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1487531731340> <BEA-101371> <There was a failure when processing annotations for application D:\Eclipse Workspace\Struts_Hibernate_Tutorial\web. Please make sure that the annotations are valid. The error is Class bytes found but defineClass()failed for: 'org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter'> 
####<Feb 20, 2017 12:45:31 AM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <Gaurav-PC> <AdminServer> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1487531731362> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID '1487531724117' for task '0'. Error is: 'weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'Struts_Hibernate_Tutorial''
weblogic.application.ModuleException: Failed to load webapp: 'Struts_Hibernate_Tutorial'
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:395)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericClassLoader.java:343)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processFilters(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:238)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processJ2eeAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:210)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(WebAnnotationProcessorImpl.java:105)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.processAnnotations(WebAppServletContext.java:1370)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:450)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.<init>(WebAppServletContext.java:494)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.HttpServer.loadWebApp(HttpServer.java:418)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.registerWebApp(WebAppModule.java:976)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.prepare(WebAppModule.java:384)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.prepare(ScopedModuleDriver.java:176)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:199)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow$1.next(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:517)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:159)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.prepare(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:45)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$1.next(BaseDeployment.java:648)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.prepare(BaseDeployment.java:191)
    at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.prepare(EarDeployment.java:59)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.prepare(DeploymentStateChecker.java:154)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.prepare(AppContainerInvoker.java:60)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.createAndPrepareContainer(ActivateOperation.java:208)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doPrepare(ActivateOperation.java:98)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.prepare(AbstractOperation.java:217)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentPrepare(DeploymentManager.java:747)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.prepareDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1216)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handlePrepare(DeploymentManager.java:250)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.prepare(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:159)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doPrepareCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:171)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$000(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$1.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:46)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

my installed java version is 1.8
my eclipse is indigo
weblogic server 10.3.6
struts 2.5

Answer (score 1):

The error

> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/filter/StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Struts2 is compiled with java7, but your server is using jdk1.6. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35985333/573032) what you have to learn how to build Struts2 with java 8.

**Use maven to build struts2 from sources. In the maven compiler plugin use the target version 1.8.**

Comment: thanks for your reply

but can i use my existing set up as my weblogic config is using the jdk 1.6 and eclipse too

and while i am installing the maven plugin it gives an error 

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.7.0.20160603-1933 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.7.0.20160603-1933)


after reading several articles i found that it cant be installed in indigo with java 1.8 in system
do i need to downgrade my java or upgrade eclipse

Comment: You have no option, the filter that you using is built with jdk7. it is the minimal requirements. But I recommend upgrade to the latest Struts release and use jdk8, I'm not sure about weblogic but it runs with Tomcat, hence Wildfly, jetty, etc. *WebLogic Server 12.1.3 is now certified on Java SE 8*.

Comment: thanks Roman

I made the changes in the java build path to refer jre 1.8
removed the weblogic from the project facets
removed unnecessary jar from struts library imported
installed tomcat 7.0
and it running fine now with tomcat

i will check the web for the weblogic

but as a beginner i will start with tomcat and will see for the weblogic later.

thanks for you support.

Comment: Please note, you can upvote and accept answer that helped you if you want to use your SO account in the future. If you are new here you should be familiar with SO and how it works. Just take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn more.