# How to disable OGNL expression evaluation for the information followed by "redirect"?

Tags: struts2, ognl

I'm using Apache Struts 2 version 2.3.14.2 to develop a web app.

I came across a method in `OgnlUtility` called `setEnableEvalExpression` to disable the OGNL expression evaluation.

Can I disable OGNL expression evaluation on the information following "redirect"?

Or Is there any other way to disable OGNL expression evaluation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: remove ognl library and [recompile struts2 from sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42332707/573032)

Comment: @AleksandrMI'm trying to achieve is that the only EL (expression language) should be used in Apache Struts. Can we do that?

Comment: @RomanCNo I don't want to remove the library..I just wanted to disable it.

Comment: You don't really, because S2 uses OGNL for internal things, like parameters. Removing it would break S2 in ways I probably don't even remember. Is your goal to disable it in JSP? If so, why? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @BSalunke Don't be afraid of the OGNL. :) It is not bad by itself, it is how do you use it.

Comment: You can't do it since it's internally integrated, the parameter is already disabled @BSalunke.